# Why does Entity make a duplicate of related item when trying to add readonly object?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I've been trying to write some tests for my program and got a strange problem.

The db looks like one-TableOne to many TableMany (let's say so)

Initialization before every test is pretty simple. Remove everything existing and insert new ones before every test. Everything works.

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void MyTestInitialize() // Before every test run.
{
    FixtureDbTearDown.TearDown( FixtureDbImport_95.ID );
    FixtureDbImport_95.SetUp();
}
```

Then I have decided to use re-use fixture and clean it up. So I made all entity classes private static readonly.

Now, only first test passes, others throw an exception on duplicate key. Running tests one by one shows no errors.

Basically, this is working

```
private static void SetUp_Many( MyEntities entity )
{
    TableMany ok1 = new TableMany { smth... };
    entity.TableMany.Add( ok1 );
}
```

But this one not.

```
private static readonly TableMany ok_sr = new TableMany { smth.. };
private static void SetUp_Many( MyEntities entity )
{
    entity.TableMany.Add( ok_sr );
}
```

Debugger shows that the second I call Add(ok_sr) entitty adds one more record to parent  TableOne.
The TableOne is an exact copy of mine, no nulls and default values.

Ok, I can make a object copy before adding, most likely, the problem is with object copy because I declare things readonly. Right?

I am a little bit confused about the duplicate for TableOne.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it's because it's `readonly`. Maybe the tests sharing the same context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The member variable `ok_sr` is `readonly` but the object `ok_sr` itself isn't!

When a member is `readonly` you can't assign another object to it after the first assignment. But if the object itself has read/write properties or state-changing methods you can still modify the object.

This is exactly what happens here. After the first test, `ok_sr` has obtained a parent, a "TableOne" instance. Now when you execute ...

```
entity.TableMany.Add(ok_sr);
```

... the parent object is marked as `Added` as well. As for EF, it's a brand new entity, even though its primary key has a value. EF just overwrites this key value.

As a general advice, I would not use static members for unit test unless it's for genuinely read-only values, i.e. value types.

A very elegant way of cleaning up in unit tests against a database (these are, in fact, *integration tests*) is to start a transaction scope in the setup of each test and dispose it without committing it in each test teardown.

Comment: Thank you, I had a strange idea that making it that way would save me some lines. I am stuck with EF5, as long as I remember transactions were introduced in EF6. One day...

Comment: That's true, but I was refering to `TrasactionScope`, which is just a .Net class.